# Cake php- cannot edit posts 403 error, but can delete

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, crud

I am using cakePHP 3.2. I can delete posts, but cannot edit them. Here is my code for controller and view.
I get 403 forbidden error when I edit and click the submit button. Any help is appreciated.Here is my code.Do I have to do anything in routes?
Thanks

```
<code>
**Usercontroller**
public function addEdit($id = null)
    {       
        if ($id == null) {

            $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
            $action = 'Add';
        } else {

            $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
                'contain' => []
            ]);
            
            $action = 'Edit';
            $this->request->data['updated'] = time();


        }
        
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {

                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user', 'action'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }
```

**view**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">
                <?= __('Users') ?>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <!--<li>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> <?/*= $this->Html->link(__("Dashboard"), ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'], ['escape' => false]) */?>
                </li>-->
                <li class="active">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> <?= $this->Html->link(__("Users"), ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index']) ?>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <i class="fa"></i> <?= __($action.' User') ?>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pages form col-xs-12 content">
        <?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?= __($action.' User') ?></legend>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('first_name', ['readonly'=>true]);
                echo $this->Form->input('last_name', ['readonly'=>true]);
                echo $this->Form->input('username');
                echo $this->Form->input('email', ['readonly'=>true]);
                echo $this->Form->input('status');
            if($action == 'Add'){
                echo $this->Form->input('password', ['type'=>'text']);
            }
            ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ["class"=>"btn btn-success"]) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link('Cancel', ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'], ["class"=>"btn btn-default spacer-left-10"]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>
```

**routes**

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
        

       $routes->connect(
    '/users/add-edit/:id',
    ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add-edit'],
    ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id']]
    );

        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    });
```

In webroot my error_logs are  :

```
Composer\Autoload\includeFile - ROOT/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php, line 412
Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass() - ROOT/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php, line 301
spl_autoload_call - [internal], line ??
class_exists - [internal], line ??
Cake\Core\App::_classExistsInBase() - CORE/src/Core/App.php, line 87
Cake\Core\App::className() - CORE/src/Core/App.php, line 64
Cake\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter::_getController() - CORE/src/Routing/Filter/ControllerFactoryFilter.php, line 91
Cake\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter::beforeDispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Filter/ControllerFactoryFilter.php, line 51
Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter::handle() - CORE/src/Routing/DispatcherFilter.php, line 145
Cake\Event\EventManager::_callListener() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 389
Cake\Event\EventManager::dispatch() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 355
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatchEvent() - CORE/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 78
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 62
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
```

Any help is appreciated as I have not been able to find out the error.

Comment: Your route has `add-edit`, but your function name is `addEdit`?

Comment: Are you using authentication? If not, the 403 is probably a misconfiguration with your server. Check your server logs. 
 The route is not necessary just the prefix part.

Comment: @styks thanks. I think you are right. Its working in my localhost. I have posted my error_logs in the code. Some classes are missing I think.

Comment: @kritika555 - I meant server logs. For Apache/httpd that would be in /var/log/apache2. The access log will show if the 403 is happening before it even gets to the cake app.